# Strange issue with MVC routing - crashing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two routes configured. One of them contains two constraints

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Sur",
            url: "sur/getsur/{key}/{opt}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Sur",
                action = "GetSur",
            },
            constraints:new { key = new GuidConstraint(), opt = new IntegerConstraint() });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Sur", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

If I try to tamper with the calling URL, i.e. not providing a correct GUID, I want my routeconfig to select the Default route instead.

Basically what I want:

test.com/sur/getsur/ANILLEGALGUID/1 - should route to the Default route.
test.com/sur/getsur/CORRECTGUID/ - should route to the Default route.

What I get with my current route setup is the following:

test.com/sur/getsur/ANILLEGALGUID/1

I get the 404.

test.com/sur/getsur/CORRECTGUID/NOINT

I get this message: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'key' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetSurvey(System.Guid, Int32)' in 'xxx.Controllers.xxx'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

test.com/sur/getsur/ANILLEGALGUID

I get this message: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'key' of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetSurvey(System.Guid, Int32)' in 'xxx.Controllers.xxx'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

test.com/sur/getsur/ANILLEGALGUID/ILLEGALINT

I get the 404.

Why is this happening? I thought that since the route isn't matched it would default to my default route. How do I fix this?

Comment: not sure you can do this with routes. my solution would be to ensure i always send a GUID to the GetSur action (either a real one or a default one) and in that action i would test the Guid and if its not correct i would redirect to the index action. OR you could create another route where K is a string (assuming an illegal GUID is sent as string) and send route that to Index.

Comment: First route should be like below,

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Sur",
            url: "sur/getsur/{key}/{opt}",
            defaults: new
            {
                controller = "Sur",
                action = "GetSur",
            },
            constraints:new { key = new GuidConstraint(), opt = new IntegerConstraint() });

Constraints name should be same as specify on URL.